# Rails - Building a ActiveRecord Query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model User and a model message.viewed_at

What I want to do is given a user, determine when they last viewed a message if ever.

Given the user, I need to find all there messages, and then sort by the most recent viewed_at at the top, and then take that record and output the viewed_at timestamp if any.

```
@user = User.find(2)
@user.find(:first, :conditions => user.messages.viewed_at != nil)
```

But that doesn't work, suggestions? Thanks

Comment: The :conditions syntax is deprecated in rails 3.

Comment: No problem, [take a look at the rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions) if you're unfamiliar with the new syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@user.messages.first(:order => "viewed_at desc")`

[Here are the docs.](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find)

`@user.messages.where("viewed_at is not null").order("viewed_at desc").first`

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work since, a user has several message and some of those messages have a viewed_at which is nil. The query above is pulling in the first record could be nil. Which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

The [rails query guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) is an excellent resource for this.

JDL's answer above will work.  Also, not sure if min/max works on dates, but if so, the method below might be more efficient:

```
@user.messages.where("viewed_at is not null").maximum("viewed_at")
```